# Can't add numbers to an array on Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, contract-debugging

i have a function that receive a number, **autentic** evaluates if it is already in an array, if it is it should return false, if it is not, return true. Then **onlyOneVote** will add the number to the array if true and not if false. The problem is the function never adds anything to the array.

```
uint32[100] public people;
uint8 public counter;

function onlyOneVote(uint32 ida) public returns(bool) {
  bool a = autentic(ida);
  if (a == true) {
    people[counter] = ida;
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
  return a;
}

function autentic(uint32 idb) public returns(bool) {
  bool b;
  for(uint i = 0; i< people.length; i++) {
    if (people[i] == idb) {
      b = false;
      break;
    } else {
      b = true;
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is safe to say that your code can be reduced to this:

```
uint32[100] public people;
uint8 public counter;

mapping (uint32 => bool) public alreadyVoted;

function vote(uint32 id) public returns(bool) {
  if (alreadyVoted[id]) return(false);
  alreadyVoted[id] = true;
  people[counter] = id;
  counter = counter + 1;
  return(true);
}
```

Call it with web3 like this:

```
contractInstance.vote.sendTransaction(id, {from: _from});
```

where `_from` is your account address (web3.eth.accounts[0] maybe).

Comment: still the same problem. when testing with IDs, no new id are in the array, still empty after the test:

    > contractInstance.vote.call(1)
    true
    > contractInstance.vote.call(1)
    true

Comment: In Ethereum, you can call functions in contracts using two different methods: call() or sendTransaction(). When the function changes the state of the blockchain (and that's the case for this function), you have to use sendTransaction().

Comment: Thank you. I have one last question, what "account address" do you refer to? dont get that part.. Sorry for so many questions XD

Comment: The account address the transaction origins from. You can use accounts[0]

Comment: it sends me "Reference Error: accounts is nit defined

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant web3.eth.accounts[0].

Answer (score 2):

This code will do it, it's tested and here you have the address to interact with it on Kovan: [0xc807caebda01eaffd7998ab7fd9fcc4a2cf5730c](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xc807caebda01eaffd7998ab7fd9fcc4a2cf5730c)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18; 


contract Test {

uint32[100] public people;
uint256 public counter; // Is uint256 because the on the array[100], 100 is a uint256 variable.
mapping(uint32 => bool) public voteVerifier; //mapping saves you so much gas at checking if it's in the array


function onlyOneVote(uint32 ida) public returns(bool) {
  require(!voteVerifier[ida]); //If false, enter to add the uint32 to array.

    people[counter] = ida; //Add the ida to the array
    counter = counter + 1;

    voteVerifier[ida] = true;//Set on the mapping that this uint32 is now on the array.
  return true;
}

}
```

A few things to comment on:

- **It's so much better to use a mapping to check if a number is on the array because it's not a time-dependent search**. Find params on arrays **makes you operate much more as greater the array becomes**. But with mappings, the search **lasts and costs the same even if millions of values were included on the array**.

Here you have some info: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings

This code: `people[counter] = ida; //Add the ida to the array
    counter = counter + 1;`

Can be replaced to be more accurate and cheaper on gas spending: `people.push(ida)//Puts on the last array's position the item ida;`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: You cannot push to an array with its size defined. people.push(id) will not compile.

Comment: I know, that's why it's not on the solution code, it's just an advice :)

Comment: Thank you for the useful advices about the mapping to use a lot less gas. i could use 'not size' defined array or mapping because the infinite loop problem and in this case i know the amount of voters, i started using push but didnt compile.

Comment: As bordalix said, push can only be used with dynamic arrays, not with fixed ones. So to limit the number of votes if you know is 100, make a require on the function that adds numbers to the array controlling it.